# How to red highlight the control on drupal forms with, form set error. while control to validate is lying in #rows attribute of parent element?

Tags: php, forms, validation, drupal, rows

I am performing some valdation, i wrote a code for validation of child elements in an array which is child of a form element and is associated to it with #rows attributes, but i am unable to pick that particular control to highlight it to the end user, that here error lies? other wise i am using drupal set message, i just need to highlight the code. I am sharing code with you people. 
THANKS FOR ANY ADVICE IN ADVANCE!

```html
$form['patient_videos'] = array(
            '#prefix' => '<div class="aa-patient-videos-container">',
           '#suffix' => '</div>',
           '#tree' => TRUE,
           '#theme' => 'table',
           '#header' => array( t('Title'),
                               t('Sent Date'),
                               t('Status'),
                               t('Customize'),
                               t('Include'),
                               t('Watched'),
                               t('No. Times View'),
                               t('No. Times Sent'),
                               t('First Send'),
                               t('Resend'),

                            ),
           '#rows' => array(),

           ###  do not put #name on the form fields
        );


$form['patient_videos'][] = array(
                'title'=>&$title,
                'sent_date'=>&$sent_date,
                'status'=>&$status,
                'customize'=>&$customize,
                'include'=>&$include,
                'watched'=>&$watched,
                'number_times_viewed'=>&$number_times_viewed,
                'number_times_sent'=>&$number_times_sent,
                'first_sent_date'=>&$first_sent_date,
                'video_id'=>&$video_id,
            );

            $form['patient_videos']['#rows'][] = array(
                array('data' => &$title),
                array('data' => &$sent_date),
                array('data' => &$status),
                array('data' => &$customize),
                array('data' => &$include),
                array('data' => &$watched),
                array('data' => &$number_times_viewed),
                array('data' => &$number_times_sent),
                array('data' => &$first_sent_date),
                array('data' => &$video_id),
            );



//USING LOOP TO ACCESS EACH ROW'S VALUES 
 foreach ($form_state['values']['patient_videos'] as $key => $value){
.
.
.
}

form_set_error('$values][patient_videos][$key][email_schedule', t("You cannot enter bigger date from next video in  ").$g);
```

how to pick each rows sent date control and highlight it if value is not true.d

Comment: Maybe this post can help http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70539/form-set-error-highlight-single-field-in-multiple-value-field

Answer (score 0):

Hey give a try to [Inline Form Error Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ife).

Comment: Hey zubi thanks , but i am working on custom forms using form api and here are 40 records that are attached with #rows attribute of a element in form